# Reinstalling Ubuntu in my partitioned laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I have a problem and I'm not sure how to proceed. I want to reinstall Ubuntu because I messed up so bad that it's the easiest way to go. My laptop is partitioned, half Ubuntu 15, half Windows 10.

How can i proceed? Is there any risk that I should think about? The BIOS of the laptop is not a Secure BIOS, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can destroy your computer.   Now that is out of the way, you should be fine.  Pay careful attention to the drive letters. The install program should detect you have ubuntu installed already and give you an option to wipe it or keep most of your files.  Choose to do a new install and delete your data (for that partitioned drive).  Do not choose to format the whole drive.  This will wipe windows too.  Simple as that.  Make sure you have a 2 gb partition as SWAP before you start.  Make it suing gparted.  Non uefi is more safer by the way.  Lastly,  Do not tweak!  I speak with experience on this one and Lubuntu is more tempting to tweak.  (I am a die hard lubuntu fan now adays).

Comment: Why would you say non-UEFI is safer?

Comment: Security problems can be a pain in the butt.  Do as you wish.  I had problems with dual boot uefi.  It worked in the beginning.. but then it was a problem.  as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot. When my ubuntu installation was messed up i just did this.

First thing did backup. You must always have a backup no matter you have raid or anything else.
I had my home folder on different logical partition. I inserted ubuntu installation USB and when prompted chose "something else"

[image]

then i marked my / aka root and swap partitions for formatting. installed ubuntu on / then when computer started i copied files from new home directory to old and made that old home directory default for new system. That's it. My dual boot was working correctly.